# How to keep screen turned off when plugging charger?

Tags: charging, screen

I have an HTC Desire. When I plug charger into my phone with screen off, it always turns the screen back on. This is slightly annoying at night.

Is it possible to configure Android so that the screen stays off and charging is only indicated via charging LED?

Comment: On my samsung galaxy S there is a timeout setting for the screen on the settings menu. You have to set the timer from infinite to some period while charging.

Comment: For my Droid, anyway, I just tap the power button to turn the screen back off.

Comment: Just my thought: my Samsung Galaxy S used to do this too when it was running Android 2.1 and 2.2. But it doesn't do that anymore now that I am running 2.2.1. I can't recall uninstalling any application so to my experience, it was the upgrade which solved this. And be sure to turn your wifi off too.

Comment: @AI E.: *Every* time I plug my phone in, I want the screen *off*, not *on*.  That means *every* time I plug my phone in, I have to "just" tap my screen.  Also, sometimes I have a flaky USB connection, so the charge keeps turning on and off; the screen then keeps coming back on, draining my battery. (Like Michael just stated happened with him.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[SnooZy Charger](http://snoozy.mudar.ca) takes care of this. The free app (as in [beer and speech](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html)) that lets you manage behavior during charger connection and disconnection.

It requires no permissions but does require you to give it the device admin permissions. These permissions are only used to control device locking, as [verifiable in its source code](https://github.com/mudar/SnooZy/blob/master/AndroidStudio/SnooZyProject/SnooZy/src/main/res/xml/device_admin.xml). From quickly going through the app’s source code, it looks totally harmless and benign.

If the app does not behave as you want, make sure to go through the Settings. For example, “Turn off screen only when locked” is enabled by default. This means that the app will not kick into effect if you have an on/off-button-press-lock delay or other related settings.

It works perfectly for my on a wireless charging pad and with a micro-USB cable using an LG Nexus 4 device. I am very satisfied.

I also documented [additional issues here](https://ctrl.blog/entry/review-snoozy-android-charging).

Comment: Bears are dangerous, not free! But seriously, this app is pretty close. Doesn't actually keep screen off, it just immediately shuts it off. One minor bug seems to be that when you unplug the phone, the screen stays off, but the buttons turn on and stay on.

Comment: I wouldn't say this app behaves "perfectly", although it's better than nothing.  The screen still turns *on*, then quickly turns back off--obviously more of a workaround than a fix.  Annoyingly, on my phone still does the silly "USB icon at the bottom that shifts your screen up", which I really just want to disable altogether.

Comment: I've used this app for some time but eventually uninstalled it. It was sometime turning my screen off when I when I was turning it on, and sometime twice in a row, not sure when or why, but this was quite annoying. What it's doing is more of a hack anyway.

Comment: I am from Brazil and I can't install it. I get this: "Sorry! This content is not available in your country yet. We're working to bring the content you love to more countries as quickly as possible. Please check back again soon." WTF. :(

Comment: I am using an old tablet as a small server. This app along with [Gravity Screen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.plexnor.gravityscreenofffree) keeps the screen off while the table is in never sleep mode.

Answer (score 7):

Do you happen to have enabled `Settings > Application > Development > Stay Awake (screen will never sleep when charging)`?

Comment: This is the same as Matt H's (now deleted) answer ... OP's comments was "The problem is not that I cannot turn the screen back off. I want it to not go on in the first place. Seems like that's not possible, sadly :-(".

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, the only way to archive this behaviour is to switch from stock Android to CyanogenMod - which does have this feature built-in (under "Display & lights" menu in preferences, disable the option "Wake on plug")

I'm also searching for a solution on stock Android, but it seems like that's the only way. Too bad, one has to change ROM just for this feature.

Comment: Do you know how does this feature work on CyanogenMod/LineageOS?

Comment: LineageOS has the same option.

Answer (score 2):

If you install Xposed, [All My...](https://repo.xposed.info/module/com.smartmadsoft.xposed.aio) module has an option to prevent the screen from waking when plugging into a charger.

Answer (score 2):

I realise this was asked a while ago but since this still comes up first in Google when you search for how to disable the coloured screen when charging a Samsung device, here the updated answer: in the settings menu under Display > Screensaver you can choose the screen saver that is shown while the device is charging. Simply set this to "none".

Comment: Which version of Android is this?

Comment: Is that a thing custom to Samsung?

Comment: @Chenmunka: I have One UI 4.1 (Android 12)

Comment: @VoY: I am not sure.

Comment: @VoY this feature is generally known as [Daydream](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2012/12/daydream-interactive-screen-savers.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is an app by mitskiP called **Screen Stay Off**. I've used it for a year and it works nicely. My only criticism is that the screen turns on briefly, then turns off.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these two in harmony:

- [Smart Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware)

  [image]
- [Black Screen - without Wake Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.binarybox.blackscreen1)

  [image]

It worked for me.

Comment: Looks like Sony's Smart Connect has been taken off from Play Store. Will this approach still work without it?

Answer (score 0):

Having the "Ambient mode" on turns the screen on while charging, even if the option "Settings > Application > Development > Stay Awake (screen will never sleep when charging)" is off.

You need to turn the "Ambient mode" off as well.

I would not suggest to install further applications only for that, while you can do the trick directly from Android.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a Tasker profile. It works by waiting for a state change and then reverting the screen state to whatever it was before said change.

Here is the copy of my `Screen.prj.xml` profile:

```
<TaskerData sr="" dvi="1" tv="6.0.10">
    <Profile sr="prof42" ve="2">
        <cdate>1658764422437</cdate>
        <edate>1658770109384</edate>
        <flags>8</flags>
        <id>42</id>
        <mid0>41</mid0>
        <nme>POWER UNPLUGGED</nme>
        <Share sr="Share">
            <b>false</b>
            <d>When you unplug your phone from a power source, have your screen automatically lock itself.</d>
            <g>Basics,Display,Security</g>
            <p>true</p>
            <t></t>
        </Share>
        <State sr="con0" ve="2">
            <code>10</code>
            <pin>true</pin>
            <Int sr="arg0" val="0"/>
        </State>
    </Profile>
    <Profile sr="prof47" ve="2">
        <cdate>1658765139741</cdate>
        <clp>true</clp>
        <edate>1658770063039</edate>
        <flags>8</flags>
        <id>47</id>
        <mid0>48</mid0>
        <nme>DISP ON</nme>
        <Event sr="con0" ve="2">
            <code>208</code>
        </Event>
    </Profile>
    <Profile sr="prof49" ve="2">
        <cdate>1658765984104</cdate>
        <clp>true</clp>
        <edate>1658770076363</edate>
        <flags>8</flags>
        <id>49</id>
        <mid0>50</mid0>
        <nme>DISP OFF</nme>
        <Event sr="con0" ve="2">
            <code>210</code>
        </Event>
    </Profile>
    <Profile sr="prof51" ve="2">
        <cdate>1658764422437</cdate>
        <clp>true</clp>
        <edate>1658770092328</edate>
        <flags>8</flags>
        <id>51</id>
        <mid0>52</mid0>
        <nme>POWER PLUGGED</nme>
        <Share sr="Share">
            <b>false</b>
            <d>When you plug your phone in leave screen on/off state alone. (Will revert screen state after android toggles it).</d>
            <g>Display,Power</g>
            <p>true</p>
            <t></t>
        </Share>
        <State sr="con0" ve="2">
            <code>10</code>
            <Int sr="arg0" val="0"/>
        </State>
    </Profile>
    <Project sr="proj0" ve="2">
        <cdate>1658764409345</cdate>
        <name>SCREEN</name>
        <pids>47,42,49,51</pids>
        <tids>46,50,41,48,52</tids>
        <Share sr="Share">
            <b>false</b>
            <d>Revert or maintain screen on/off state after power plugged in or out.</d>
            <g>Display,Power</g>
            <p>true</p>
            <t></t>
        </Share>
    </Project>
    <Task sr="task41">
        <cdate>1650476952536</cdate>
        <edate>1658769236054</edate>
        <id>41</id>
        <pri>100</pri>
        <Action sr="act0" ve="7">
            <code>547</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%STARTED</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">%TIMES</Str>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg4" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg5" val="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg6" val="1"/>
            <ConditionList sr="if">
                <bool0>And</bool0>
                <Condition sr="c0" ve="3">
                    <lhs>%STARTED</lhs>
                    <op>13</op>
                    <rhs></rhs>
                </Condition>
                <Condition sr="c1" ve="3">
                    <lhs>%SCREEN</lhs>
                    <op>2</op>
                    <rhs>on</rhs>
                </Condition>
            </ConditionList>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act1" ve="7">
            <code>547</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%UPTIME</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">%TIMES-%STARTED</Str>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg4" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg5" val="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg6" val="1"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act2" ve="7">
            <code>548</code>
            <on>false</on>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%UPTIME</Str>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg10" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg11" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg12" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg13" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg14" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg3" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg5" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg6" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg7" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg8" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg9" val="1"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act3" ve="7">
            <code>248</code>
            <Int sr="arg0" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="1"/>
            <ConditionList sr="if">
                <Condition sr="c0" ve="3">
                    <lhs>%UPTIME</lhs>
                    <op>6</op>
                    <rhs>1</rhs>
                </Condition>
            </ConditionList>
        </Action>
    </Task>
    <Task sr="task46">
        <cdate>1658764707914</cdate>
        <edate>1658765118823</edate>
        <id>46</id>
        <nme>Dont Screen On On Power</nme>
        <Action sr="act0" ve="7">
            <code>548</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%SCREEN</Str>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg10" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg11" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg12" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg13" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg14" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg3" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg5" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg6" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg7" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg8" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg9" val="1"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act1" ve="7">
            <code>248</code>
            <on>false</on>
            <Int sr="arg0" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
            <ConditionList sr="if">
                <Condition sr="c0" ve="3">
                    <lhs>%SCREEN</lhs>
                    <op>2</op>
                    <rhs>off</rhs>
                </Condition>
            </ConditionList>
        </Action>
    </Task>
    <Task sr="task48">
        <cdate>1658765152954</cdate>
        <edate>1658767756538</edate>
        <id>48</id>
        <nme>Display Uptime</nme>
        <pri>6</pri>
        <Action sr="act0" ve="7">
            <code>547</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%STARTED</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">%TIMES</Str>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg4" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg5" val="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg6" val="1"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act1" ve="7">
            <code>548</code>
            <on>false</on>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">started %STARTED</Str>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg10" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg11" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg12" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg13" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg14" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg3" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg5" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg6" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg7" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg8" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg9" val="1"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act2" ve="7">
            <code>549</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%STOPPED</Str>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
        </Action>
    </Task>
    <Task sr="task50">
        <cdate>1658766071199</cdate>
        <edate>1658769148172</edate>
        <id>50</id>
        <nme>Reset Screen Uptime</nme>
        <pri>6</pri>
        <Action sr="act0" ve="7">
            <code>547</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%STOPPED</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">%TIMES</Str>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg4" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg5" val="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg6" val="1"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act1" ve="7">
            <code>548</code>
            <on>false</on>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">Stopped %STOPPED</Str>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg10" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg11" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg12" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg13" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg14" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg3" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg5" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg6" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg7" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg8" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg9" val="1"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act2" ve="7">
            <code>547</code>
            <on>false</on>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%UPTIME</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">0</Str>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg4" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg5" val="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg6" val="1"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act3" ve="7">
            <code>549</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%STARTED</Str>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
        </Action>
    </Task>
    <Task sr="task52">
        <cdate>1650476952536</cdate>
        <edate>1658769822832</edate>
        <id>52</id>
        <pri>100</pri>
        <Action sr="act0" ve="7">
            <code>548</code>
            <on>false</on>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%STOPPED</Str>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg10" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg11" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg12" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg13" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg14" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg3" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg5" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg6" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg7" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg8" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg9" val="1"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act1" ve="7">
            <code>547</code>
            <on>false</on>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%STOPPED</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">%TIMES</Str>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg4" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg5" val="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg6" val="1"/>
            <ConditionList sr="if">
                <bool0>And</bool0>
                <Condition sr="c0" ve="3">
                    <lhs>%STOPPED</lhs>
                    <op>13</op>
                    <rhs></rhs>
                </Condition>
                <Condition sr="c1" ve="3">
                    <lhs>%SCREEN</lhs>
                    <op>2</op>
                    <rhs>off</rhs>
                </Condition>
            </ConditionList>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act2" ve="7">
            <code>547</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%DOWNTIME</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">%TIMES-%STOPPED</Str>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg4" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg5" val="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg6" val="1"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act3" ve="7">
            <code>547</code>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%DOWNTIME</Str>
            <Str sr="arg1" ve="3">0</Str>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg3" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg4" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg5" val="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg6" val="1"/>
            <ConditionList sr="if">
                <Condition sr="c0" ve="3">
                    <lhs>%STOPPED</lhs>
                    <op>13</op>
                    <rhs></rhs>
                </Condition>
            </ConditionList>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act4" ve="7">
            <code>548</code>
            <on>false</on>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">Downtime %DOWNTIME</Str>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg10" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg11" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg12" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg13" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg14" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg3" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg5" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg6" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg7" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg8" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg9" val="1"/>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act5" ve="7">
            <code>806</code>
            <on>false</on>
            <Int sr="arg0" val="216"/>
            <ConditionList sr="if">
                <Condition sr="c0" ve="3">
                    <lhs>%DOWNTIME</lhs>
                    <op>6</op>
                    <rhs>2</rhs>
                </Condition>
            </ConditionList>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act6" ve="7">
            <code>248</code>
            <Int sr="arg0" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="1"/>
            <ConditionList sr="if">
                <Condition sr="c0" ve="3">
                    <lhs>%DOWNTIME</lhs>
                    <op>7</op>
                    <rhs>1</rhs>
                </Condition>
            </ConditionList>
        </Action>
        <Action sr="act7" ve="7">
            <code>548</code>
            <on>false</on>
            <Str sr="arg0" ve="3">%DOWNTIME</Str>
            <Int sr="arg1" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg10" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg11" val="1"/>
            <Int sr="arg12" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg13" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg14" val="0"/>
            <Int sr="arg2" val="0"/>
            <Str sr="arg3" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg4" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg5" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg6" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg7" ve="3"/>
            <Str sr="arg8" ve="3"/>
            <Int sr="arg9" val="1"/>
        </Action>
    </Task>
</TaskerData>
```

Comment: Hello. No third-party link dependent answer please. I have added the content of XML file in your answer. A more readable solution to share Tasker profiles is to mention the steps needed to create the Profile and the Task. E.g. Profile: Action -> some_Action. Task: app -> launch app -> do_this

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue and fixed it by first turning on "Developer mode" then deselecting "Stay awake" under Settings / Developer Options. Turn on developer mode by going to Settings / About Device, then touch/tap on "Build number" seven (7) times. Once developer mode is on, go to Settings / Developer Options, and deselect "Stay awake".

This resolved the problem for me.  Keep in mind that each Android phone is slightly different in where "About Device" is located, but it is in the Settings section. Go there and tap "Build number" seven times to turn on Developer mode.

Comment: Stay Awake keeps the screen on all the time, and is not enabled by default.