# Phone wakes when unplugged, how to keep it asleep?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, charging, htc-evo

I'm trying to charge my phone with an inconsistent power source.  Unfortunately, the phone wakes up whenever power stops... Sometimes (often) using more power than is charged.

Is there a way to stop the trigger to wake when charging ends?  What is the internal name for this trigger?

My workarounds so far share the same fault:  I can't receive calls.  It can't wake if I turn it off, and it doesn't use too much power (usually) in airplanr mode.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably doable, but I very much doubt that you can do this with the default (unmodified) factory firmware. Custom firmwares such as CyanogenMod may allow you to do this. Your mileage may vary and you may even need to modify or recompile these custom firmwares to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to stop that behavior through OS,and I found no reference either. Connect it either to a UPS if the drop out period is long otherwise connect it through a stabilizer if the current drops at a very higher rate, like a blinking of a bulb. Otherwise I don't think it would be good for your phone's charging system.

You could also use USB charging.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like this behavior either and even though I have a custom (or more like modified) stock ROM (removing the bloatware and rooting it) it didn't change this behavior. However, I found that setting the screen timeout to the lowest value of 15 seconds did the trick in that it would force the phone to go back to sleep by shutting off the screen in 15 seconds after it comes to life, this meant that there was minimal loss of power while unattended, maybe that would help you since there is no way to stop the behavior altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The [SnooZy app](http://snoozy.mudar.ca) will let you manage this. (See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/60254/23686) for details.)