# How to make screen stay turned on while charging?

Tags: charging, 5.1-lollipop, screen

I have 2 devices: one with Android 4.2.1 (Emotion UI 1.6), one with Android 5.1.

Android 4 device has an option in "developers" settings to always keep screen turned on while charging. Android 5 device seems not have "developers" settings at all, and I couldn't find such an option to keep screen turned on while charging anywhere.

Could I somehow tell my Android 5.1 device not to turn off the screen after timeout, when charger is plugged?

Comment: This question is an antonym to question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8280/how-to-make-screen-stay-turned-off-when-plugging-charger

Comment: Antonio, have you already [enabled developer settings](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/developer-options/info) on the Android-5 device? They started to hide them around 4.2/4.3.

Comment: @Izzy yahoo! it helps! would you please write compete "answer" to this question, so I could accept it?

Comment: Sure, done :) Enjoy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This option is still there in developer settings. Those settings have just been hidden since around Android 4.2/4.3. Our [developer-options tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/developer-options/info) shows you how to enable them:

1. Go to *Settings → About*
2. tap the *Build number* entry 7 times (hammering the item)
3. Go back to the *Settings* main page, *Developer Settings* should now be visible

In there you'll now find the option to "keep display on".