# How to stop screen from coming on with intermittent charging

Tags: charging

I know we have this very old question and answers
[How to keep screen turned off when plugging charger?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8280/how-to-keep-screen-turned-off-when-plugging-charger)
but why isn't this implemented by Android?

My scenario is that I use my phone for navigation on my bike, and it's connected to a hub dynamo charger.  The charger output isn't buffered so it will stop charging if I go too slowly (a hill or traffic lights, etc), and then start again when I'm up to speed.  This can cause the screen to come on a lot.  Ideally I would like to disable this behaviour.
What's the current best solution and why doesn't Android have a check box to disable this annoying behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

One of the earlier [answers](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8280/how-to-keep-screen-turned-off-when-plugging-charger) on this recommend using [Snoozy](http://snoozy.mudar.ca/). However it's no longer on Google Play, so you have to load the APK directly from the website mentioned.